# Python 2.6 XML Parser assertionError

Tags: python, xml, python-2.6, xml.etree

I am having an error while parsing an XML document on my zenoss server in python. How do I get around the error/fix the error?

Here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('/root/Dropbox/Public/N8800Space.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <value>125</value>
        <label>Used</label>
        <colour>FFFF10AA</colour>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>125</value>
        <label>Free</label>
        <colour>FF0010AA</colour>
    </item>
</root>
```

Here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geckoBoard.py", line 2, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse('/root/Dropbox/Public/N8800Space.xml')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 586, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1245, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1188, in _end
    return self._target.end(self._fixname(tag))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1096, in end
    self._last.tag, tag)
AssertionError
```

Also if I do it with etree I get a UnicodeEncodeError

Code:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse('/root/Dropbox/Public/N8800Space.xml')
root = doc.getroot()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geckoBoard.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 123, in init lxml.etree (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:156336)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the entire xml file? I checked the source code, and it seem like the module believes you have an end tag mismatch. But I can run the xml (fromstring) fine on my machine.